# Get request to cordova.file.dataDirectory fails with status -1

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm building a ionic cordova project and I need to access cordova.file.dataDirectory. However, the request always fails in iOS (works well on android using externalDataDirectory). I'm trying to do a get request as follows:

```
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'configuration.json'
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         //success!

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
      });
```

the failed response returns:

```
{  
   "data":null,
   "status":-1,
   "config":{  
      "method":"GET",
      "transformRequest":[  
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[  
         null
      ],
      "url":"file:///Users/xsuser4/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C21A5E3B-26A4-4962-90B3-9F533D1E85AE/data/Containers/Data/Application/35EC6C2E-47F8-4DEE-95EE-12AEEC4ACAAA/Documents/configuration.json",
      "headers":{  
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
         "Authorization":"bearer (followed by long string)"
      }
   },
   "statusText":""
}
```

I am sure the file exsists. I believe that the GET request is not being sent by the $http because the staus is -1. I'm using "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3".

Is there something that I'm missing in order to make it work on iOS?

Thanks!

Comment: use ionic file https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/ - once you have it setup...`this.file.dataDirectory` instead of `cordova.file.dataDirectory`